# How do we use LSTM to classify sequences?

Tags: machine-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

LSTM is good for predicting what is going to happen after a sequence, but I assume that we have many sequences and that each sequence corresponds to a class label.

How can we use LSTM to classify these sequences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LSTM can be used for prediction as well as classification tasks.

For classification, you can follow most commonly used architectures that I have described below. However, you can build your own model depending on your requirement.

As the output of LSTM (Here I explain dynamic_rnn with time_major == False), we have a tensor with a shape of **output = [batch_size, sequnce_length, cell.output_size]**, which means that for each row in the batch we have [sequnce_length, cell.output_size].

***1. Method 1***

[image]

***1. Method 2***

[image]

Hope this helps.