# LSTM cells after convolution

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, convolution

I need to implement an LSTM layer after a two convolutional layers. Here is my code after the first convolution:

```
convo_2 = convolutional_layer(convo_1_pooling, shape=[5, 5, 32, 64])
convo_2_pooling = max_pool_2by2(convo_2)
convo_2_flat = tf.reshape(convo_2_pooling, shape=[-1, 64 * 50 * 25])
cell = rnn.LSTMCell(num_units=100, activation=tf.nn.relu)
cell = rnn.OutputProjectionWrapper(cell, output_size=7)
conv_to_rnn = int(convo_2_flat.get_shape()[1])
outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, convo_2_flat, dtype=tf.float32)
```

I get this error on the last line:

```
ValueError: Shape (?, 50, 64) must have rank 2
```

I have to indicate the time steps into the `convo_2_flat` variable, right? How? I really don't know ho to do that.

EDIT:
After this reshape:

```
 convo_2_flat = tf.reshape(convo_2_flat, shape=[-1, N_TIME_STEPS, INPUT_SIZE])
```

where

```
N_TIME_STEPS = 25
INPUT_SIZE = int(64 * 50 * 25 / N_TIME_STEPS)
```

I got this error: InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): logits and labels must be same size: logits_size=[5000,7] labels_size=[50,7] on this line:
cross_entropy = `tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_true, logits=outputs))`
Seem to me that the batch size has changed after the last reshape.

EDIT 2:
Is it wrong the code below?

```
convo_2_shape = convo_2_pooling.get_shape().as_list()
shape_convo_flat = convo_2_shape[1] * convo_2_shape[2] * convo_2_shape[3]
N_TIME_STEPS = convo_2_shape[1]
INPUT_SIZE = tf.cast(shape_convo_flat / N_TIME_STEPS, tf.int32)
convo_2_out = tf.reshape(convo_2_pooling, shape=[-1, shape_convo_flat])
convo_2_out = tf.reshape(convo_2_out, shape=[-1, N_TIME_STEPS, INPUT_SIZE])
```

I set `N_TIME_STEPS` that way because otherwise I'll have a float `INPUT_SIZE` and tf will throw an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Tensorflow documentation (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn)

Input should be in the following shape (I use the default here),
[image]

*i.e.,* **[BATCH_SIZE, N_TIME_STEPS, INPUT_SIZE]**. Therefore, you can reshape **convo_2_flat** as follows,

```
#get the shape of the output of max pooling
shape = convo_2_pooling.get_shape().as_list()
#flat accordingly
convo_2_flat = tf.reshape(convo_2_pooling, [-1, shape[1] * shape[2] * shape[3]])

# Here shape[1] * shape[2] * shape[3]] = N_TIME_STEPS*INPUT_SIZE

#reshape according to dynamic_rnn input
convo_2_flat = tf.reshape(convo_2_flat, shape=[-1, N_TIME_STEPS, INPUT_SIZE])

outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, convo_2_flat, dtype=tf.float32)

# get the output of the last time step
val = tf.transpose(outputs, [1, 0, 2])
lstm_last_output = val[-1]

OUTPUT_SIZE = 7 #since you have defined in cell = rnn.OutputProjectionWrapper(cell, output_size=7)

W = {
        'output': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([OUTPUT_SIZE, N_CLASSES]))
    }
biases = {
        'output': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([N_CLASSES]))
    }

#Dense Layer
pred_Y= tf.matmul(lstm_last_output, W['output']) + biases['output']
#Softmax Layer
pred_softmax = tf.nn.softmax(pred_Y)

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_true, logits=pred_softmax))
```

Note on the **outputs**:

According to the documentation, output of the  dynamic_rnn is as follows,

[image]

*i.e.,* **[BATCH_SIZE, N_TIME_STEPS, OUTPUT_SIZE]**. Therefore, you have an output for every time step. In the above code, I only get the output of the last time step. Alternatively, you can think about a different architecture for rnn output that describes as here ([How do we use LSTM to classify sequences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46750692/how-do-we-use-lstm-to-classify-sequences/46752762#46752762)),

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is: isn't input size  64 * 50 * 25 (from my code)?

Comment: 64 * 50 * 25 = N_TIME_STEPS * INPUT_SIZE, therefore, u need to define those two parameters.

Comment: Thanks, now I get another problem and I think is caused from the reshape. I edited the question. Can you help me please?

Comment: Doesn't work, it gives me a wrong number of predictions, greater than the batch size. Can you explain me why you added 
`val = tf.transpose(outputs, [1, 0, 2])
lstm_last_output = val[-1]` ?

Comment: I added some changes to the code and added explanations whenever I think necessary. Let me know whether the code is working or not and you want further explanations.

Comment: Thank you, you've been very clear. I edited the the question, hoping that's the last time.

Comment: I think should be okay. The requirement is N_TIME_STEPS and INPUT_SIZE should be integers and N_TIME_STEPS *  INPUT_SIZE = shape_convo_flat.

Comment: Ok, Thank you very much.

Comment: By the way, `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` already internally scale the logits. if you input logits that already performed the softmax then you perform the softmax twice on your logits, which will produce incorrect results.